# Backup, sync and search files over internet and intranet

Tags: backup, networking, search

There are many online backup options out there. Dropbox, Sugarsync, Mozy, Carbonite, Jungledisk and my favorite so far, [Crashplan](http://blog.iharder.net/2010/02/19/crashplan-for-live-offsite-backup/).

Some of them allow searching, all of them sync with their online servers, none of those (or many many others I didn't listed here) have what I want. I'm **not** looking for an online backup service in here.

Sure, some people might say "use rsync", "linux" and/or "set up apache" and so on... But that's just too much for maintenance, if it's even viable of building up. **It needs to be simple**.

**So, anyone knows of a really good solution out there?**

Picture mostly [Google Desktop Search](http://desktop.google.com/features.html#search) (or quick search) awesome searching, mixed with [Crashplan Desktop](http://b5.crashplan.com/consumer/download.html), which is able to do everything by itself, and something like [Dropbox's file versioning](https://www.dropbox.com/help/11), along with dropbox the ability to seamless sync over intranet and internet like crashplan, switching between them when needed. I bet there's nothing like this yet, but well, I'm not sure. It would be great!

Comment: Can you clarify this for us please mate?  You say you're not looking for an online back soln, but your question says it is for internet and intranet.  This sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: @Steve I've modified it a little, see if it's better. About "online service" vs "internet", a software needs internet to go online (that's why I changed the wording there) but what I mean by *online service* is a host and a company behind it. I want a software able to do everything on its own, online and over the internet when needed to connect to other softwares, without relying on anything else other than itself or its copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tonido](http://tonido.com/) comes extremely close.

Comment: Sounds freaking amazing! Why just "close"? I'll check myself if it's missing anything. :D

Comment: @Cawas looking now, they added search in fact. I've been using it since way before they added that, and hence...

Comment: I still have to try it myself, but it's being growing since then and I believe it does answer the question now!